# How do I make this code show days until the event, not days since the event

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have the following code :

```
//Age

@IBOutlet weak var daysLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var monthsLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var yearsLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func birthday(sender:AnyObject){
    var dateComponents = NSDateComponents()

    dateComponents.day = 19
    dateComponents.month = 12
    dateComponents.year = 2015

    let certainDate = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!.dateFromComponents(dateComponents)!
    let durationDateComponents = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!.components( [.Year, .Month, .Day, .Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: NSDate(), toDate:certainDay, options: [])

    yearsLabel.text = "\(durationDateComponents.year)"
    monthsLabel.text = "\(durationDateComponents.month)"
    daysLabel.text = "\(durationDateComponents.day)"
}
```

This code is counting how many days it's been since that day, but it will not count down, why is that? How do I achieve this?

Comment: If I changed `certainDay` to `birthDate` I got the number of years, months & days until that date - what do you want?

Comment: No, it should be certainDate. And it won't show me years, months, and days to the date, it shows me it FROM the date for some reason.

Comment: I ran your code and got 0 years, 2 months 11 days which seems right to me

Comment: @Paulw11, I got 18 days, 1 hour, and 2 minutes and it's just stuck there. This same exact code.

Comment: This is a straight copy-paste from my playground - https://gist.github.com/paulw11/d6b1be47d3f6bc20eaf6.  Your code doesn't say anything about hours, minutes or seconds

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, but this snippet will give you the days until my next birthday. :)

```
let now = NSDate()
let birthdayDay = 23
let birthdayMonth = 8
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let thisYear = calendar.component(.Year, fromDate: now)
let bdayComponents = NSDateComponents()
bdayComponents.day = birthdayDay
bdayComponents.month = birthdayMonth
bdayComponents.year = thisYear
var bdayDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(bdayComponents)!
var timeLeft = bdayDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(now)

if (timeLeft < 0) {
    bdayComponents.year = thisYear + 1
    bdayDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(bdayComponents)!
    timeLeft = bdayDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(now)
}

let componentsUntilBday = calendar.components(.Day, fromDate: now, toDate: bdayDate, options: NSCalendarOptions.MatchStrictly)
print("Scott's birthday is in \(componentsUntilBday.day) days!")
```

**Updated code to use suggestion in comments**

Comment: Uhm, how do I make this display on a label? This code isn't really clear to me.

Comment: This code should not be used. Not every day has 84600 seconds.

Comment: @rmaddy you are correct, and I wouldn't suggest anyone use this in a banking app, but I think we can let the idea of a standard day slide for his birthday countdown app. Still, it's a naive implementation and would welcome a more elegant solution for my education.

Comment: Look into the `NSCalendar components:fromDate:toDate:options:` method.

Comment: @AmitNivedanKalra Put this code into a Playground and see how I got to the days until my birthday. You can use something similar to update the text of a UILabel. If you want this to count down continuously, then you will need to look into how to use a timer like NSTimer to call this code every time interval you specify.